# Java api - Class names starting with _ [underscore]

Tags: java, api, classname

I’m interested to know this as they are part of Java api [J2SE].

Generally it a convention to use "_" in variables name to indicate that they're instance variable or for some other special purpose [but defiantly it depends on programmer’s taste].

But there are **few classes** listed in Java API [J2SE], whose names are starting with underscore ("_").

Really Oracle have any special meaning/purpose for this underscore? [If yes,] Why kind of difference these classes have when compared with other classes in same API?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

_BindingIteratorImplBase
_BindingIteratorStub
_DynAnyFactoryStub
_DynAnyStub
_DynArrayStub
_DynEnumStub
_DynFixedStub
_DynSequenceStub
_DynStructStub
_DynUnionStub
_DynValueStub
_IDLTypeStub
_NamingContextExtStub
_NamingContextImplBase
_NamingContextStub
_PolicyStub
_Remote_Stub
_ServantActivatorStub
_ServantLocatorStub

Comment: They are in the `org.omg` package (and other packages with that prefix). Most likely they are implementation classes, and they are not actually part of the Java API.

Comment: "Generally it a convention to use "_" in variables name to indicate that they're instance variable or for some other special purpose": Not in Java. A convention of this kind is required in C++ because of the constructor syntax for member variables. There is no such requirement in Java, hence it is rarely used, and only by people who think they're still programming in C++. The classes you mention were all defined by OMG in the early 1990s according to the naming restriction imposed by CORBA IDL, which again have nothing to do with Java.

Comment: @EJP: I see you're just like me, posting too much as a comment. More often than not you're giving a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks. It started out as a comment but grew like Topsy. I've posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those classes are not really Java classes, they are part of the CORBA implementation and are generated from programming-language-independent IDL definitions - the naming convention is a CORBA one.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how to conclude that they are part of CORBA IDL, Will there be any indication in JAVA API for this [i.e. this class is implementation of CORBA IDL]?

Comment: @VenkateshAchanta anything under the `org.omg` package hierarchy is CORBA related and will use CORBA naming conventions rather than the usual Java ones.

Answer (score 8):

> Generally it a convention to use "_" in variables name to indicate that they're instance variable or for some other special purpose

Not in Java. A convention of this kind is required in C++ because of the constructor syntax for member variables. There is no such requirement in Java, hence it is rarely used, and only by people who appear to think they're still programming in C++.

The classes you mention were all defined by OMG in the early 1990s according to the naming restriction imposed by CORBA IDL, which again have nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 2):

There is no special reason for that, again.. it's a matter of taste.

However, if you want to fully follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), you should avoid appending `_` to the name of a class.

It's redundant to append `_` to class members as well, most IDEs color these fields with a different color and you can easily distinguish them from local variables. I see this piece of code more elegant:

```
public MyConstructor(int field) {
    this.field = field;
}
```

Than

```
public MyConstructor(int field) {
    _field = field;
}
```

But again, it's still a mater of taste and it might be that your company works with it, so you don't want to be the first one to break it.

Comment: I use the underscore prefix in C#, because - while frowned upon occassionally - it does function as a convention and I've seen it in high quality source code, for instance in Entity Framework. Not so in Java, hence I don't. In Rome do as the Romans do. Interestingly though, in Android Studio, when you add a new activity, the skeleton code that gets generated for you uses `m` prefix for class members (`mSectionsPagerAdapter` and the like), which I always thought of as a no-no, even worse than the underscore.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Naming Conventions for Packages, Class and variables]

Here's the table of naming convention that one should follow while writing java code.

You can start a class name by '_' but it is not recommended.

Comment: Half this table consists of merely repeating the rules of Java, which you *can't* break. No 'should' about them.